# Getting Cannot find class in classpath exception when running test suite

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver, testng

In my Maven project, i have my individual tests running properly.

Though i configure these tests in testng, they are working fine when ran individually.

```
<suite name="Suite1" verbose="1" >
  <test name="Test Suite" >
    <classes>
       <class name="test1" />
       <class name="test2" />
    </classes>
  </test>
</suite>
```

But what i want is i want to run all tests, for that i am using below:

```
<suite name="Run all tests" verbose="1" >
  <test name="Run entire Test Suite" >
    <classes>
       <class name=".*" />
    </classes>
  </test>
</suite>
```

Here i am getting below error: `org.testng.TestNGException: Cannot find class in classpath: .*`

I tried cleaning the project -> clean and 
Maven -> Update project
Build path -> Source -> Configure each folder points to class files "Allow output folders to source folder"

But none help. Can someone help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

TestNG doesn't support regex on `<class>` tag.

Instead, and if you are able to specify it, you can use the `<package>` tag (which may not support regex either).

Comment: Unfortunately i dont have any special package. All my cases are in default(src\test\java) folder itself. I say other threads specifying wild characters (.*) with package and class names. Are we missing any project level configurations here?

Comment: There are many places i found that they use wildcard regular expressions. One such example article: http://www.testingexcellence.com/testng-run-all-test-classes-package-testngxml-suite/